# Datatables .row() is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, datatables

i want to delete rows by simply clicking related Button.. **data tables is works, i can use some basic function like sort and search in datatable**, but when i click the button it just simply said undefined error :

for your information, im using datatable 1.10 and jquery 1.10.2
[image]

Code :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="row-border" id="table">
<thead>
    <th>Video ID</th>
    <th>Filename</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABCD</td>
    <td><input type='button' name='deleteBtn' value='Delete' />
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Video ID</th>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = $('#table').dataTable( {} );

$('#table tbody').on('click',"input[type='button']",function() {
    table
        .row( $(this).parents('tr') )**
        .remove()
        .draw();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put your script inside $(document).ready(function{});

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It does not work, because there is a huge difference between the `dataTable()` constructor and the `DataTable()` constructor introduced in 1.10.x ([see docs](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10)) :

> The difference between the two is that the first will return a jQuery
>   object, while the second returns a DataTables API instance.

Simply change

```
var table = $('#table').dataTable( {} );
```

to

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable( {} );
```

if you want to work on the new dataTables API through the `table` variable.
See your code working -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Sd6UQ/**

NB : Remember to use `<tr>`..`</tr>` and close `<td>`'s properly. dataTables can be very sensitive to malformed markup.

Comment: For clarity's sake: the difference is between `dataTable()` with an initial lowercase letter (old) and `DataTable()` with an initial uppercase letter (new). Mentioning it explicitly as I overlooked it the first time I read it... :-)

Comment: Great answer ! time saver .

Answer (score 0):

if you decide to create the datatable on this way

> table = $('#table').dataTable( {} )

you will obtain a jQuery object in table var
but you can access to the dataTable api with the following instruction

table.api()

you could see it running here

http://jsfiddle.net/Sd6UQ/

you could use that Technic if you have no access to the datatable creation instruction

```
<script>
    //datatable creation is in another file
    //$('#table').dataTable( {} )

    $("button[name'deleteBtn']").click(function(){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var table = row.closest('table').dataTable();
        table.api()
             .row( row )
             .remove()
             .draw();
    })
<script>
```

you could see it working here

http://jsfiddle.net/r2ue74zn/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the following code to reload datatable

```
//var table = $('#table').dataTable( {} );
table.ajax.reload();
```